# How to organise model that consists of several lists

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model

I have a model that consists of several lists that are used in a news feed. For example, there are different lists for sport stories and car stories. I am wondering how I should organise these.

```
class  NewsFeed{

    public List<SportStory> sportStories;
    public List<CarStory> carStories;
    public Map<int, String> storyType;
    public Map<int, int> storyPositions;

    public String getType(int position){
        storyType.get(position);
    }

    public String getPositionInList(int position){
        storyPositions.get(position);
    }

}

class SportStory{

    public String sportName;
    public String imageUrl;
    public String notablePlayer;
    public int favourites;

}

class CarStory{
    public int storyType;
    public String carName;
    public String carType;
    public String carColor;


}
```

The view then renders the stories in the model with the correct template by checking what type the story is using the `getType` function. It gets the story position using the `getPositionInList`.
For example say the view was rendering the fifth story. It would use the `getType` function and find out it was a car story. It would then use the `getPositionInList` to see that the fifth story in the news feed corresponded to the second item in the car story list.
Another problem I have is that if different types of stories are added then this class has to be changed.

If an event is triggered on the view a callback is in invoked on a controller.

```
   public void onSportStoryFavourited(int id){
        SportStory story = getSportStoryById(id);     
        story.favourites = story.favourites + 1;
        dao.updateSportStory(story);
        view.onStoryFavourited(id);       
   }
```

I don't really think this approach is sound at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making a new `Story` class. It could be an almost empty class, but it could contain something useful like `dateWritten` that would apply to all kinds of `Story`s. Then, you could simply have your `CarStory` or `SportStory` extend your parent class `Story`.

Then, your newsfeed wouldn't contain cumbersome `List<SportStory>` and `List<CarStory>`, but only `List<Story>`.

If you needed to check what type the story is, then you could use `instanceof` instead of keeping track of a map from `int` to the description. For example, you could do `someStory instanceOf SportStory` which would return `true` if `someStory` is of type `SportStory`.

Comment: How would the view or the controller get specific types of the data from the different story objects though, cast? The different stories could contain vastly different data.

Comment: @Benten In your Story superclass you can have a type instance variable and getType() accessor. You can call this method on Story objects to see what type of story they are, cast them accordingly and handle them from there.

Comment: @Benten You might want to accept this answer if it helped you.